# Color code in 2010

Tags: 2010

How do I color code a row in a lists based on a 'Status" field. Essentially calculated field based on status column. I tried a feature called Spotlight which [image]

Comment: Check this https://blog.splibrarian.com/2012/06/06/using-calculated-columns-to-add-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/

Comment: Hi @jinny the attached link for 2007 and 2010 not only 2007 !! scroll down to check the section related for 2010 !!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

in June 2017, Microsoft disabled the use of JavaScript in a Calculated Column

That means given answers may not apply  for newer SharePoint versions

For long explanation and work arounds see:
[June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f/218110#218110)

---

**Original answer:**

The answer in the comments refers to the SP2007 style, where you needed extra JavaScript in a CEWP to convert a Calculated Column.

Since SP2010 executing HTML/JS can be done straight from the Calculated Column,
by setting the datatype to anything but Single Line of Text

See:

- http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

for examples see

- http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/

And I tagged all my answers of the past years with ICC:

- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a32871%20ICC

answers with 'color':

- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A32871+ICC+color